# Number of ways to form a mountain ranges

Tags: java, algorithm, catalan

I am looking at an application of catalan numbers:

Number of ways to form a “mountain ranges” with n upstrokes and n down-strokes that all stay above the original line.

[image]

Now given a number n, find the number of mountain ranges.

```
public int countMountainRanges(int n) {

}
```

What logic or formula can we use here to get the number of ways for input `n`.

I tried the formula F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2), but it does not work in this case.

Comment: well what's the definition of mountain? e.g., `//\/` with N=2 is a mountain?(i mean up up down up, I can't add spaces on comments)

Comment: maybe https://mathcircle.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/BMC6/pdf0607/catalan.pdf page 2

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia, yes the link you shared has complete information about mountain ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)` is the formula for the nth Fibonacci number. The nth Catalan number, on the other hand, is given by (2n choose n) / (n + 1).

```
public static int countMountainRanges(int n) {
    return choose(2 * n , n) / (n + 1);
}
private static int choose(int n, int k){
    int res = 1;
    k = Math.min(k, n - k);
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        res = res * (n - i) / (i + 1);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, can you please tell me how this logic solves the given problem. Just trying to understand what approach I need to follow if I see similar kind of problems in futures.

Comment: @learner You can take a look at the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Proof_of_the_formula

Comment: Can you please explain the lines `Math.min(k, n - k)` why we need the min also why `n-k`. Then `res * (n - i) / (i + 1)`.

Comment: @learner n chose k is equal to n chose(n-k), so that line chooses to perform the minimum possible times

Comment: @learner n choose k is equivalent to the product of the integers from n - k + 1 to n divided by the product of the integers from 1 to k.

Comment: `res * (n - i) / (i + 1)` here, I am not able to relate your statement `n choose k is equivalent to the product of the integers from n - k + 1 to n divided by the product of the integers from 1 to k` can you please elaborate?

Comment: @lierwu, I am trying to understand by taking an example say n=6, k = 2. So Given 10 choose 2, is the same as Given 6 and choose (6-2)=4. can you please explain how this possible?

Comment: @learner It is just combining two loops into one. The product of `(n-i)` where `i` ranges from `0` to `k - 1` is the same as the product of the integers from `(n - (k - 1))` to `(n - 0)` or `n - k + 1` to `n`. The product of `(i + 1)` where `i` ranges from `0` to `k - 1` is similarly the product of the integers from `0 + 1` to `k - 1 + 1` or `1` to `k`. The product of the integers from `n - k + 1` to `n` divided by the product of the integers from `1` to `k` is the binomial coefficient of n and k.

Comment: @learner Also take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849758/why-n-choose-k-n-choose-n-k for a proof of why n choose k is equal to n choose n - k.

Comment: @lierwu, sorry type, it is 6 not 10.